# Clarification on Ruby syntax in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, syntax

I'm learning Rails and in going through the official [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html), I came across some code which I could not really understand the meaning of.

Case 1 -

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

It looks to me that `validates` is a method that takes a symbol called `:name` as an argument. But then, what is `presence`? Is it also a method? But if it is, what is the significance of the `:` right after `presence`. I understand that the value `true` is being set for `presence`, which serves as kind of a validation, requiring the presence of (in other words). But I'm not quite clear on the syntax.

It might also be possible that `presence: true` is just a hash, where `:presence` (the symbol) is the key, and `true` is the value.

Case 2 -

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  validates :terms_of_service, acceptance: true, message: 'must be abided'
end
```

Again, `validates` is the method that takes a symbol `:terms_of_service` as an argument. But what about the rest? Is it a hash with 2 key-value pairs, somewhat like `{acceptance: true, message: 'must be abided'}`?

And if it is indeed a hash, why is it tacked on to the `validates` method in each case? Why can't it be

```
validates :terms_of_service
acceptance: true, message: 'must be abided'
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: They're just hashes. How you format it is up to you (within the confines of Ruby grammar).

Answer (score 5):

That is the syntax for passing a hash to the method. What that is doing is the same thing as `validates(:terms_of_service, {acceptance: true, message: 'must be abided'})`. It's a common way of passing extra options to a method.

Comment: Thanks! I've mostly worked with Java and JS before, so I'm kind of used to the `()` around the method. Have to get used to the lack of that in Ruby.

Comment: The reason for the (optional) lack of parens in ruby is so that sometimes it will be more readable. For example: `puts "hi"` rather than `puts("hi")` or  `refute "This".equals "That"` rather than `refute("This".equals?("That"))`  (minitest). It also allows comparison operators to be methods, for example `a == b` is the same thing as `a.==(b)`, and this method can be overridden/modified.

Answer (score 3):

In Ruby there's a strong tradition for passing in options as a Hash as the last argument, strong enough that this tradition became new feature borrowed from Python: Keyword arguments.

In classic Ruby the method would be defined as this:

```
def validates(*args)
  options = args.last.is_a?(Hash) ? args.pop : { }

  # args is a list of fields
end
```

In Ruby 2.3 you can do this:

```
def validates(*args, **options)
  # options is automatically any hash-style arguments if present
end
```

In Ruby 2.0+ you can also do this:

```
def validates(*args, acceptance: false, message: nil)
end
```

Where that defines options as first-class variables.

It's a common Ruby pattern, so it's good to understand what's going on here. Try writing your own methods that take options and you'll see how it plays out.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info! I've read about the `splat` operator - `*`, have to look into the `**` now!

Comment: This answer is much more detailed than mine, I didn't even know `**arg` is valid syntax. Thanks!